# How can I use set list to highlight otherwise invisible characters, except when those characters are tabs?

Tags: vim

I want to use `set list`, but with the exception of tabs, so tabs would just look like spaces.

This is my current configuration, but tabs still have a different background colour:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:\ \ ,eol:#,trail:~
```

[image: Screenshot]

I don't want tabs to be highlighted, but I do want trailing whitespace and EOL to be highlighted. How could I do this? (I could edit the color scheme, but that feels like an ugly hack.)

Comment: Remove the tabs from the setting? `set listchars=eol:#,trail:~`

Comment: @FDinoff That highlights tabs as `^I`, which is even worse. :)

Comment: Ah didn't realize it would do that. (I'm not sitting in front of my computer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that.

The help for [`'listchars'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27listchars%27) states

> The "NonText" highlighting will be used for "eol", "extends" and "precedes".
>   "SpecialKey" for "nbsp", "tab" and "trail".

That is to say

- `tab` and `trail` get the `SpecialKey` highlighting
- `eol` gets the `NonText` highlighting
- space gets the `Normal` highlighting

You are free to link these highlighting groups any way you like with `:hi`, but as far as I know you cannot change the highlighting groups they belong to. See [`:h :hi-link`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3ahi-link).

```
:set listchars+=tab:\ \ 
:hi! link SpecialKey Normal
```

Comment: I've set the `hi! link SpecialKey Normal` in my vimrc, but it doesn't do anything. Its still using the colorscheme's colors. `:verbose hi SpecialKey
SpecialKey     xxx term=bold ctermfg=243 ctermbg=235 guifg=#808080 guibg=#343434
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-colorschemes/colors/candyman.vim`

Comment: `space` for me now at least maps to `SpecialKey`, not `Normal` anymore.